# jQuery ajax isnt working?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Can anyone see why this jQuery ajax isn't working?  It's supposed to run every second, but it isn't running at all.

Source code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{

var ID = $(this).attr("id");
if(ID)
{
$("#more"+ID).html('<img src="moreajax.gif" />');

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "ajax_more.php",
data: "lastmsg="+ ID, 
cache: false,
success: function(html){
$("ol#updates").prepend(html);
$("#more"+ID).remove();
}
});
}
else
{

}


return false;

}, 10000);
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure but I think the first parameter of setInterval is  the function name as a string, not the function itself.

Comment: @Eliasdx: You are wrong.  It is possible to pass a string of executable code to `setTimeout`, but that should not be done.  Pass a function.

Comment: Wouldn't this run every 10 seconds? Are you sure it's not running or are you just not waiting long enough?

Comment: Changed it too 1 and still nothing.

Comment: @user Did you check the error console in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ID = $(this).attr("id");
```

In the context you've provided `$(this)` will resolve to an empty set. Thus your later check `if(ID)` will always be false.

You should pass an actual selector to `$()` to select the dom element you want to get the ID of.

Answer (score 0):

try removing the:

`return false;`

also you have the setInterval to run every 10000 ms which is equal to 10 seconds.